# Minimal postfix config to receive email

Tags: email, postfix

I have do.ma.in with next DNS records:

```
do.ma.in      A   a.b.c.d
mail.do.ma.in A   a.b.c.d
do.ma.in      MX  mail.do.ma.in
```

I want to receive one mail from `mail.google.com` to my postfix to only one address `postmaster@do.ma.in` or at least to `root@do.ma.in`

So, I installed pure `postfix` to machine `a.b.c.d` and edited next options in  `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
myhostname = mail.do.ma.in
mydomain =do.ma.in
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit
```

The other settings are default. Then I fully restarted postfix daemon `service postfix restart`.
But when I send mail to `root@do.ma.in` I can't see anything in maillog, only "started" messege which was generated on daemon restart:

```
Feb 11 19:20:29 CentOSPC postfix/master[16510]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
```

`postqueue -p` is also empty

But if I capture traffic to 25 port `tcpdump -vv -x -X -s 1500 -i eth1 'port 25'` I see something when I send mail from gmail (my host is `192.168.0.48` and 25 port is NAT-ed from host `192.168.0.49`, which have interface with `a.b.c.d`):

```
   192.168.0.49.33301 > 192.168.0.48.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0x179b (correct), seq 1811629667, win 42900, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 822583720 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 107e 0000 2e06 fa8c c0a8 0031  E..<.~.........1
    0x0010:  c0a8 0030 8215 0019 6bfb 4663 0000 0000  ...0....k.Fc....
    0x0020:  a002 a794 179b 0000 0204 0596 0402 080a  ................
    0x0030:  3107 a1a8 0000 0000 0103 0307            1...........
19:23:20.492856 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40) 
192.168.0.48.smtp > 192.168.0.49.33301: Flags [R.], cksum 0xf990 (correct), seq 0, ack 1811629668, win 0, length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0028 0000 4000 4006 b91e c0a8 0030  E..(..@.@......0
    0x0010:  c0a8 0031 0019 8215 0000 0000 6bfb 4664  ...1........k.Fd
    0x0020:  5014 0000 f990 0000                      P.......
```

So what I missed, what options need to be add to config?

Here is `postconf -n`

```
[root@CentOSPC]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, do.ma.in
mydomain = do.ma.in
myhostname = mail.do.ma.in
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign domains for local delivery (do.ma.in in your case) to `mydestination` variable in `main.cf`

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, do.ma.in
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I added `do.ma.in` to the end of `mydestination` and updated `postconf` in question, but it still not works.

Comment: do you see attempts to deliver mail to `root@do.ma.in` in `/var/log/maillog`?  
Even better if you add `tail -50 /var/log/maillog` to your initial post

Comment: No, it is still empty, but `tcpdump` still shows one SMTP package when I send email to `root@do.ma.in` from gmail

Comment: join the chatroom with the same name

Comment: The reason was in some settings that prevented logging, so I removed /etc/postfix/ folder and reinstalled postfix, and now maillog shows delivers, and I able to read mail.